# fujitsu-usb-touchscreen on kubuntu 13.04 (64-bit) on P1630: `make` errors

Tags: touchscreen, make, fujitsu-siemens

I installed Kubuntu 13.04 (64-bit) on my new Fujitsu LifeBook P1630, and added just a few packages:

First `aptitude`, then I did `aptitude update && safe-upgrade`, then `xinput-calibrator` (which seems to work, except that I have to run it again every time I restart the system), then `gcc`, `make`, `build-essential`, `checkinstall`, `binutils`, and `linux-source`.

Then I downloaded the file
[cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406.zip](https://bitbucket.org/cybergene/fujitsu-usb-touchscreen/get/112fdb75b406.zip) which is linked from the page https://bitbucket.org/cybergene/fujitsu-usb-touchscreen/overview
(I'm assuming it's the elusive v0.3.9, which doesn't seem to be linked under that name from anywhere); I extracted its contents to a directory
`~/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406`
and attempted to run `make`.  The console (er, Konsole) trace is below:

```
archelon@ingelrayok:~/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406$ make
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-30-generic/build M=/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.o
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c: In function ‘usb_u810_tablet_irq’:
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:133:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘dbg’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:182:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘err’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c: In function ‘usb_u810_tablet_probe’:
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:246:6: error: called object ‘err’ is not a function
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:253:6: error: called object ‘err’ is not a function
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:263:6: error: called object ‘err’ is not a function
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:270:6: error: called object ‘err’ is not a function
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:277:6: error: called object ‘err’ is not a function
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:302:5: error: called object ‘err’ is not a function
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:358:5: error: called object ‘err’ is not a function
/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c:366:5: error: called object ‘err’ is not a function
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-30-generic'
make: *** [fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.ko] Error 2
archelon@ingelrayok:~/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406$
```

I should also note that `make` completes without errors on my other computer, a Toshiba Satellite R10 running Kubuntu 12.04; this machine also has a (fully operational) tablet with stylus. (The Toshiba's tablet is a Wacom with active digitizer as opposed to the Fujitsu's USB resistive touchscreen).  So, probably I'm just missing some package or other---I haven't compiled anything for years and never was particularly good at it.  Perhaps you can sort me out.

UPDATE:  I've replaced 13.04 with 12.04 LTS, retaining my /home partition, and now the package compiles: `make` completes without errors.  However, `make install` does not.  [To be precise, I ran `checkinstall` (or, rather, `sudo checkinstall`), which calls `make install`, because as far as I can tell the former is a simple upgrade of the latter (at least for my purposes), providing integration with the package management system.] Initially, it failed with the following error:

```
make: execvp: /etc/init.d/fujitsu_touchscreen: Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 127
```

After some research, I tried using `chmod +x` on the affected file:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/fujitsu_touchscreen
```

Running `sudo checkinstall` again, the permission error is seen to have been resolved; it gets much further along before failing again.  The log which it offers to print to stdout shows a `dpkg` error, as follows:

```
dpkg: error processing /home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to create `/sys/module/fujitsu/usb/touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy.dpkg-new' (while processing `/sys/module/fujitsu/usb/touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy'): No such file or directory
```

And, indeed, while there is `/sys/module/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy`, there is no `/sys/module/fujitsu/usb/touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy`; apparently a typographical error has been introduced somewhere.  Thus I must find and fix it.  But unfortunately I have very little idea where to look other than the `install;` section of the makefile, and it's not in there. (I understand there is sometimes an `install` file instead?  But there isn't in this case.) ...Help?

(Since this is an entirely distinct issue, I've asked a separate question: [`make install` fails apparently due to typo, but not in makefile: How to find and fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346740/make-install-fails-apparently-due-to-typo-but-not-in-makefile-how-to-find-an))

**UPDATE 2013-10-18**
After reinstalling Kubuntu 12.04 again, this time recreating the /home partition (which, again, had been generated during an install of 13.04), I can no longer reproduce the strange error immediately above. I am still curious to know how the underscores got changed to slashes, but it looks as though nobody has any idea. It is perhaps also of interest to note that while I have still not successfully run `checkinstall` against this package, I have done `make install`; it requires the executabilization of `/etc/init.d/fujitsu_touchscreen` and the installation of `hal`, and the GUI freezes shortly after installation completes, and there is no particular new functionality afterwards that I have noticed, and the system can no longer resume from being suspended.  I have subsequently lost interest in `fujitsu-usb-touchscreen` since it appears the [Magick Rotation](https://launchpad.net/magick-rotation) package can provide everything I was looking for.  It does not, however, work 'out-of-the-box'; I have filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/magick-rotation/+bug/1240589) which also documents the inelegant workaround I discovered.

Answer (score 1):

fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c says it's v0.3.9, despite the enclosed README file reporting "Fujitsu usb touchscreen kernel module and utilities v0.3.5". I hate saying this, but "it works for me":

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/cybergene/fujitsu-usb-touchscreen/get/112fdb75b406.zip
unzip 112fdb75b406.zip
cd cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406
make
```

Three possibilities:

1. Possibly the zip file is corrupt? Try downloading again and repeating the extract/make steps?
2. Make sure you have the current linux-headers package installed (this is needed for the inludes: linux/kernel.h, linux/slab.h, linux/module.h, linux/init.h, linux/usb/input.h). e.g.: `find /usr/src/ -iname slab.h`
3. The package author does say, "Drop me an email if you have trouble installing the package." Have you tried that yet?

--beg:edit

I've been testing this in VirtualBox guests. The one I had it working under was installed from kubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso some time ago and probably has some extra headers kicking around that made it happy.

I just installed a clean guest from kubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso and was able to repro your error. Not sure what's going on there, but if in fujitsu_usb_touchscreen.c I add the following lines immediately after the includes then it compiles without error:

```
#define dbg(args...) printk(args)
#define err(args...) printk(args)
```

Also, the usb_u810_tablet_probe() function defines an `int err` which is confusing to humans vs. the `err()` function/macro.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does it really say that?

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, seriously. In the README file which is quoted on the overview page you linked.

Comment: 1. Tried it again with wget, just in case. Same result.  2. Each of those *.h names gives multiple results in that path.  3. Yes, almost 24 hours ago now.

Comment: Is that on 13.04 that it works for you? Or is that extremely unlikely to be relevant?

Comment: Still no response from zmiq2...  I suppose I'll try downgrading my installation from the Recumbent Rodent to the Pusillanimous Porcupine, since I've seen the package compile on the latter.  I'm trying to balance the productivity gain I would get from having this working against the loss incurred by working on it.  If only I could think of some other prerequisite package(s) I could plausibly be missing!

Comment: Perhaps I am too impatient, but I am going to replace 13.04 with 12.04 LTS and try again to compile the fujitsu-usb-touchscreen package.

Comment: Sorry, been stuck at work the last coupla days. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Your efforts are greatly appreciated. Since I am now (temporarily) running 12.04, and since I need to concentrate on my GR and QFT classes for a bit (despite not having the stylus to take notes and do homework), there may be some latency in my own engagement with this. Now, I understand that you are defining both `debug(args...)` and `err(args...)` as `printk(args)`, but in my vast ignorance of C, I must ask the following: are `arg` and `arg...` to be taken literally?  If so, what are they, anyway?  And if not, to what do they refer?

Comment: These are macro definitions, so they get expanded out to "printk(whatever parameters were in the original code)" at compile time.

I probably shouldn't be using printk() for both dbg() and err(). I should go through the currently set of headers and find out where their proper definitions are missing from.

In C you can define (args...) as your function parameters to tell the compiler that you accept a variable number of parameters, just like the printf(), sprintf() and fprintf() functions do. You can mix it up and have required parameters such as:

void foo(int bar, bool baz, args...) {...}

Comment: I apologise for abandoning this thread; after much travail, I lost interest in `fujitsu-usb-touchscreen`, since I couldn't get it to do anything---at least, not anything good---and I eventually discovered a way to get Magick Rotation to work instead.