# `make install` fails apparently due to typo, but not in makefile: How to find and fix?

Tags: drivers, dpkg, make, fujitsu-siemens, checkinstall

I'm trying to install the [fujitsu-usb-touchscreen](https://bitbucket.org/cybergene/fujitsu-usb-touchscreen/get/112fdb75b406.zip) drivers from [here](https://bitbucket.org/cybergene/fujitsu-usb-touchscreen/overview), on Kubuntu 12.04 on my new Fujitsu LifeBook P1630. (See [fujitsu-usb-touchscreen on kubuntu 13.04 (64-bit) on P1630: `make` errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345639/fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-on-kubuntu-13-04-64-bit-on-p1630-make-errors).) I downloaded the .zip file, unzipped it, and ran `make` in the directory thus created; this all worked as expected.  However, when I run `sudo checkinstall` (which invokes `make install`), things go less well.  On the first attempt the installation aborted with the following error:

```
make: execvp: /etc/init.d/fujitsu_touchscreen: Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 127
```

I eventually resolved this by

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/fujitsu_touchscreen
```

But although a second `sudo checkinstall` then does not give the `execvp` error, it still fails at a later stage, and the log (on stdout) shows this `dpkg` error:

```
dpkg: error processing /home/archelon/fujitsu-touchscreen-driver/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen-112fdb75b406_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to create `/sys/module/fujitsu/usb/touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy.dpkg-new' (while processing `/sys/module/fujitsu/usb/touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy'): No such file or directory
```

And, indeed, there is no `/sys/module/fujitsu/usb/touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy`; there is, however, `/sys/module/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy`, and this is presumably what was intended.  But this incorrect filename does not appear in the makefile or any other file in the directory, at least not that I can find.  Nor does it appear, as I discovered after running `sudo checkinstall --install=no` as suggested below, in the .deb package created by checkinstall.

Where might such a typographical error be originating, and how would I go about fixing it?

**Edited to add:** I'm viewing the contents of the .deb file with `ark`, Kubuntu's default tool.  It contains only three files: `control.tar.gz`, `data.tar.gz`, and `debian-binary`. `data.tar.gz` contains the directory tree that appears to match up to the usual root filesystem, with /etc, /lib, /sys, and /usr directories. (Looking at other .deb files on my system, this structure appears to be typical.) Here's a screenshot:
[image: Ark window with contents of data.tar.gz].
([Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEkbF.png).)

Here's another screenshot showing that `control.tar.gz` contains three files, one of which is empty:
[image: Ark windows showing the rest of cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen_112fdb75b406-1_amd64.deb].
([Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjpaR.png).)

Here's the actual .deb file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/odwxxez0fhyvg7a/cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen_112fdb75b406-1_amd64.deb

**Edited 2013-09-28 to add:**

After reinstalling Kubuntu 12.04 again, this time recreating the /home partition (which, again, had been generated during an install of 13.04), I can no longer reproduce this error.  I am still curious to know how the underscores got changed to slashes, but it looks as though nobody has any idea.  It is perhaps also of interest to note that while I have still not successfully run `checkinstall` against this package, I have done `make install`; it requires the executabilization of `/etc/init.d/fujitsu_touchscreen` and the installation of `hal`, and the GUI freezes shortly after installation completes, and there is no particular new functionality afterwards that I have noticed, and the system can no longer resume from being suspended; however, this will be pursued elsewhere.

Comment: As the error is with `dpkg`, probably the culprit is `checkinstall`. Try to run `sudo checkinstall --install=no` (this will only create the package, not installing it), and inspect the package contents.

Comment: @Salem: I have done this and am none the wiser. (Well, I learned what the inside of a .deb package looks like, which is nice.) The file `cybergene-fujitsu-usb-touchscreen_112fdb75b406-1_amd64.deb` that was created by checkinstall contains three files, of which one is `data.tar.gz`; this file includes `/sys/module/fujitsu_usb_touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy`, as I imagine it should. (It also contains three other files in that directory with similar names, ending in 'miny', maxx', and 'minx'.) Any more hints?

Comment: Why has my question been downvoted, if I may be permitted to ask?  Am I missing something excruciatingly obvious?  I am certainly capable of that.  If so, then feel free to downvote me as much as you please, provided only that you *tell me what it is.*

Comment: which program are you using to open the .deb file? If you use Archive Manager (`file-roller`) it should show you a folder named `DEBIAN` inside and the layout the package will have after being installed. As `sys` is a "dynamic" folder probably the statement to create `/sys/module/fujitsu/usb/touchscreen/parameters/touch_maxy.dpkg-new` may be in any script in the DEBIAN folder.

Comment: BTW if you could upload and share the generated .deb would help to see if the problem is indeed with `checkinstall`.

Comment: My apologies for taking so long to do this.  As you can see there are no scripts in the `DEBIAN` folder, and no `DEBIAN` folder.  Perhaps the binary performs the equivalent function?  That seems unlikely, I suppose.  When I read the `checkinstall` README file more carefully, I started to worry that it might not be as compatible with Ubuntu as I had blithely assumed.  Then I noticed how old the document was and laughed at myself.  Then I checked the version number in the README... and the version number on my `checkinstall`... They're the same.  Is this, after all, a potential concern?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with checkinstall that generates file system errors such as you have demonstrated above. In my own usage of checkinstall I routinely use the following option with my command line to get around a probable bug:

```
sudo checkinstall --fstrans=no
```

The man pages give this:

> --fstrans 
> Enable/disable filesystem translation. Filesystem translation enabled causes the install to proceed in a temporary directory, thus not actually touching your system.

Not a satisfactory solution but until the bug is fixed it seems to be required...